# RANSAC algorithm to find line parameters of an image and draw the line

Tags: python, image-processing, ransac

I have these two images :

[image]

[image]

I should use the RANSAC algorithm to find line parameters of them and draw the best line on them.

Here is an implementation of RANSAC algorithm:

[link](https://salzis.wordpress.com/2014/06/10/robust-linear-model-estimation-using-ransac-python-implementation/)

The algorithm's first step is to select random data from original data.  How can I use the image as input?

Comment: you need to convert you image into points array

Comment: The image contains line too,  what should i do with those lines?how can i ignore it?

Comment: Please upload the image. I don’t see it.

Comment: i forgot to upload it, i edited the post

Comment: So what exactly are you asking?  Your title asks for one thing, but your question asks for another.  Also, what have you tried?  FYI, it's **RANSAC**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply a matter of finding all points that are non-zero in the image.  Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to find all coordinates that are non-zero.

```
(y, x) = np.where(img)
```

`img` is the image, assuming it is grayscale.  `y` would be the row locations and `x` would be the column locations.  You'd use these to feed into the code seen in the post.